# How to write case when in where statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle, case

I wrote below statement. In MySQL it executes ok, but in Oracle it fails with error:

> meg:ORA-00905: missing keyword

How should I write this SQL?

```
SELECT count(*)   
FROM  userTable 
WHERE ( CASE WHEN mac IS NULL THEN mac IS NULL ELSE mac = '000fe95erd32' END )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up two ways of doing case. You either need:

```
CASE <expression>
WHEN <comparison expression> THEN <return expression>
…
```

or

```
CASE
WHEN <condition> THEN <return expression>
...
```

your query is malformed

```
SELECT count(*)   
FROM  userTable 
WHERE ( CASE WHEN mac IS NULL THEN mac IS NULL ELSE mac = '000fe95erd32' END )
```

your clause is not well good. you can do it differently
 like this :

```
SELECT count(*)   
FROM  userTable 
WHERE mac is null or mac = '000fe95erd32';
```

You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580026/missing-keyword-ora-00905-oracle-sql-case-statement) for further information.

Comment: if I want use CASE  WHEN statement in this business logic,how shoud i do?

Comment: The `OR` suggestion is good but there is nothing mixed in the OP's query. It would even work correctly if Oracle had a boolean datatype.

Comment: thanks ,  I use OR  to solve it at last. And I found oracle is unable to output statement in CASE WHEN

Comment: the oralce is able to output  the value of condition in CASE WHEN statement,like below:  <i>SELECT count(*) FROM  userTable  WHERE ( CASE WHEN MAC = '000fe95erd32' THEN  1 WHEN MAC IS NULL THEN 1   ELSE 0 END)=1 <i/>

Comment: The asker isn't really mixing up ways of using case; it's just that Oracle doesn't have a Boolean datatype, so you can't even do `SELECT mac IS NULL FROM userTable`.